# How to copy focused link in Firefox on Linux?

Tags: linux, firefox, accessibility, focus

I have motor problems with my right hand, and so I drive my GUIs mostly with the keyboard.

Using the pointer (either mouse or any substitute) is not impossible, but slow and hard.

One of the things I have not figured out yet is how to easily copy links from webpages I'm reading in the browser. I can focus links by starting the "Quick search" i.e. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd>, or <kbd>'</kbd>, and when a link is focused I can open a new tab on it with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. But sometimes I'd like to copy just the URL without opening it, for example when it is something else than `http` or `https`.

Note that this is different from the context menu you get from right-clicking on a link. Right-clicking acts on the link under the pointer, this question is about the *focused link*.

I use Firefox on Linux. Linux is non-negotiable but if this feature exists in another browser I'll consider it.

Answer (score 2):

The extension
[Fast Copy Links by ColdSpirit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fast-copy-links/)
is described as :

> For copy link - hover cursor on link and press Ctrl+C (MacOS: Cmd+C).
> You can to open menu and copy list of all copied links before!
>
> The permission to "Access your data for all websites" is necessary for
> absolutely all extensions that run on the site pages. This extension
> performs the following actions on the pages of the site, so it also
> needs this permission.
>
> 1. Detects when a key is pressed (Ctrl+C/Cmd+C).
> 2. Gets a link under the cursor.

If it works for you, this could be a solution.

Comment: thanks, sadly the operative words are "Hover cursor" and "link under cursor". Not what I'm after. It's actually really depressing how people reflexively suggest purported solutions involving the mouse, even though my very first sentence explains how that is unsuitable.

Comment: I hoped that it will pick up the link that you selected using your method. Sorry that this didn't work for you. I'll see if I can find something else.

Comment: Question: Do [Mouse Keys](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-mouse-keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer-9e0c72c8-b882-7918-8e7b-391fd62adf33) help?

Comment: Excellent question! Yes, I do use MK - I would probably kill myself if they didn't exist :( . But: 1. even with MK, it is a terrible chore to position the pointer over a link - it's just too small a target. and 2. MK go away with Wayland - I'm lucky I'm on a distro / desktop that hasn't switched yet.

Comment: On the phone I many times need to zoom into the page to click on a small link. Perhaps you can do this with MK for precision.

Comment: I was going to say that zooming in Firefox was also way inconvenient (I can only go 1 step at a time). But it turns out the desktop has its own zoom feature, and it does work with Firefox (ie. when I click in the zoomed view it does the right thing). So this helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Caret Browsing (`F7`) the following work-around is possible:

- Select *all* of the link text using keys like `Control+Shift+Left` and `Control+Shift+Right`
- Right click to get a context menu. Independent of the cursor position, there's an item "View selection source", pick it. New tab opens with the source code for the page with the corresponding part centered and selected.
- The link  URL will be right next, so select it, then copy with `Control+C`.

This is a bit longer and more complex than I hoped, but it does beat trying to place the mouse precisely on the link so I can right click it (for me, YMMV).

The reason Caret Browsing is needed is to be able to move the selection in steps 1 and 3 as well as to extend it.